# How to add institute and conference info with logos in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I want to add institute logo and conference logo in my beamer front slide to look something like this[image]

The code I am using is here:

```
      \documentclass[a4paper,aps,umbc4,9pt,colorBG,slideColor]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}\justifying % left-right alignment
\usepackage{txfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=12pt, text margin right=12pt}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left, leftskip=5mm]
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\newcommand{\backupbegin}{
    \newcounter{finalframe}
    \setcounter{finalframe}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
    \setcounter{framenumber}{\value{finalframe}}
}
\newcommand{\dprime}{\prime \prime}

\date{}
\title[ Title ]{\huge\textcolor{green}{Title of the presentation}}
%\subtitle{subtitle here}
\author[Author name]{ \large{\textcolor{blue}{Name } }}
\institute[Institute]{ {\textcolor{blue}{Institute}}\\
    {\textcolor{blue}{Inst. Address line 1}}\\
    {\textcolor{blue}{Inst. Address line 2}}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible approach, easy to adjust and change.

It uses the `nicematrix` package to place the text content and images in two rows with two columns each.

The `\Block{}{<content>}` command allows you to insert content (text or images) into the cells.

Notice that the figures are vertically aligned and centered with the text on the left.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,aps,umbc4,9pt,colorBG,slideColor]{beamer}
    
\usepackage{ragged2e}%\justifying % left-right alignment
\usepackage{txfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=12pt, text margin right=12pt}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left, leftskip=5mm]
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\newcommand{\backupbegin}{
    \newcounter{finalframe}
    \setcounter{finalframe}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
    \setcounter{framenumber}{\value{finalframe}}
}
\newcommand{\dprime}{\prime \prime}

\date{}
\title[ Title ]{\huge\textcolor{green}{Title of the presentation}}
%%%\subtitle{subtitle here}
%%%\author[Author name1]{ \large{\textcolor{blue}{Name 1} }}
%%%
%%%\author[Author name2]{ \large{\textcolor{blue}{Name 2 } }}
%%%
%%%\institute[Institute]{ {\textcolor{blue}{Institute}}\\
%%% {\textcolor{blue}{Inst. Address line 1}}\\
%%% {\textcolor{blue}{Inst. Address line 2}}
%%%}

\usepackage{nicematrix}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle 
    \vspace*{-50pt}% adjust 
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{wl{0.5\textwidth}l}
            \Block[l]{}{%
                {\large\textcolor{blue}{Name 1}} \\
                {\large\textcolor{blue}{Name 2}}    \\
                \textcolor{blue}{Inst. Address line 1}\\
                \textcolor{blue}{Inst. Address line 2}
            } & 
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
        \end{NiceTabular}\vspace*{30pt}% adjust 
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{wl{0.5\textwidth}l}
        \Block[l]{}{Conference name} & 
        \Block{}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \vfill  
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```